# Centering CSS/HTML main div

Tags: css, html, styles, centering

SOLVED
Thanks Marek,

I think those were changed as she played around with it, I have however after opening the files in notepad++ noticed the colors were off. Somehow 3 of the double quotes were italicized and that was causing the HTML to ignore main. problem solved. I will direct her to your answer for help with cleaning up her code.

Thanks again!

My girlfriend is doing her html homework and is running into a problem centering her main div.

please excuse any mistakes I make as I do not know HTML. I am studying C++ which is not terribly useful. However patiently debugging and researching an answer is not showing me the problem, especially as the given example does work with the same code.

I have recommended stack overflow because this site has helped me in the past. While this question looks like a duplicate None of the provided answers have solved the problem and I believe that the solution is something that a beginner would think is unrelated to the problem although I cannot confirm.

CSS style:

```
body {
background-image: url(../images/bg.gif);
margin: 0 ;
font: 11px "Trebuchet MS", Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
color: #7C3404;
line-height: 18px;
text-align: center;
}

#main {
background-color: #FFFFFF;
border-left: 2px solid #000;    
border-right: 2px solid #000;
border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
width: 700px;
margin: 0 auto;
text-align: left;
position: absolute;
}

h1 {    
font: 14px “Georgia”, Times, serif;
font-weight: bold; 
color: #7C3404;
padding: 0px 25px 0px 25px;
width: 700px;
margin: 0 auto;
}

p {
padding: 0px 25px 0px 25px;
}

ul {
margin-left: 40px;
padding-right: 60px;
list-style: url(../images/bullet.gif);  
width: 700px;
margin: 0 auto;
}

a {
font-weight: bold;
color: #AD3110;
text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
font-weight: bold;
color: #6B0808;
text-decoration: underline overline;
}
```

HTML index:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Chelsea Palmer + Exercise 2</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id=“main”>
<img src="images/header.jpg" alt=“Flying solo” height="250" width=“850" />
<h1> That’s Right, it’s time to fly solo! </h1>
<p> So now it’s your turn to show us what you’re made of! So what do you need to do to show us that you can fly on your own? Here are the criteria for this exercise: </p>
<ul>
<li> Apply the background image so it repeats, no matter how large the browser is! </li>
<li> Set up the layout as similar to what you see in this screenshot </li>
<li> The heading should be implemented with h1 tag. Assign the following properties and values: font-size 14px, Georgia, bold, color #7C3404. </li>
<li> The body copy should be 11px, Trebuchet MS or sans-serif, color #7C3404. Also the line height should be 18px.</li>
<li> Maintain site organization (that means create folders for images, css) </li>
<li> Use proper naming conventions (no spaces, crazy characters, all lowercase) </li>
<li> The html page should be named index.html </li>
<li> Include doctype and four main tags </li>
<li> Use external CSS file to apply style to your document. Style the links so that they are bold and they have a border above and below when they are hovered. </li> 
<li> Apply a custom bullet to this unordered list. </li>
<li> Create external links for the three links below that will open in a new browser window. </li> 
</ul>

<h1> Notable sites to see! </h1>
<p> 
Here are a few notable sites to check out in your spare time to get inspired and learn more about html & css
</p>
<ul>
<li> <a href="http://www.cameronmoll.com" target="_blank">http://www.cameronmoll.com</a> - Learn from Captain America, Cameron Moll. </li>
<li> <a href="http://www.cssbeauty.com" target="_blank">http://www.cssbeauty.com</a> - Get inspired and learn tricks of the trade </li> 
<li> <a href="http://www.stylegala.com" target="_blank">http://www.stylegala.com</a> - Keep up to date and inspired at stylegala </li> 
</ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try to change:

```
#main {
background-color: #FFFFFF;
border-left: 2px solid #000;    
border-right: 2px solid #000;
border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
width: 700px;
margin: 0 auto;
text-align: left;
position: absolute;
}
```

to

```
#main {
background-color: #FFFFFF;
border-left: 2px solid #000;    
border-right: 2px solid #000;
border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
width: 700px;
margin: auto;
text-align: left;
}
```

Simply - remove absolute positiong and change margin to "auto" only.

Comment: Also text-align: left is redundant as it is the default option I guess